# Excel, Finding Data in a Column, then posting the data in an adjoining column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vba

[Excel Visual Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LhZT.png)

I am looking to setup a formula to search Sheet 1, Column A for a specific term, in this case "PPG", then write the data from Column B of Sheet 1 into Column A of Sheet 2.

Sheet 2, shows the list I would like to have displayed.  How do I write a formula to pull the data from "Sheet 1", find the instances of PPG, pull the data in Column B and write then in Column A of "Sheet 2", then go to the subsequent lines to find other instances?  Do I need to write a Macro to run?

I have 
=IF(A3=PPG,"B3","") however I'm not sure how to write it to find the next instance so if I have several lines between PPG data, it doesn't show up in the output.

Comment: I'm not sure i plainly understood your needs. Maybe you should have a look at the "vlookup" function, or search on keywpord "pivot table"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try,

```
=index(sheet1!b:b, aggregate(15, 6, row($3:$6)/(sheet1!a$3:a$6="ppg"), row(1:1)))
```

fill down for second, third, etc.

Comment: Can you explain a little, I'm not sure what all the functions are doing but have an idea and would like to understand more.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by fill down, will I have to put this in for every row on the output sheet (Sheet 2)?

Comment: 1. google *excel fill down*. 2. I'm not here to rewrite documentation (which it appears you haven't bothered to read) nor be your personal tutor. Read the documentation at support.office.com and if you have a **specific** question on a point you do not understand, then post a comment back here.